# Why does my function double the result to the array instead of adding one result to it?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to recreate the game Simon on JavaScript. It seems to be going well, except I am using an array to log previous rounds. After passing one round, instead of adding one item to the array, it doubles the length of the array.

The project is a work in progress right now so the game should not work as intended but this error acts as a roadblock and I cannot make anymore progress until this is fixed.

```js
var audioContext = new AudioContext();

function playFrequency(frequency) {
  // create 2 second worth of audio buffer, with single channels and sampling rate of your device.
  var sampleRate = audioContext.sampleRate;
  var duration = sampleRate / 2.5;
  var numChannels = 1;
  var buffer = audioContext.createBuffer(numChannels, duration, sampleRate);
  // fill the channel with the desired frequency's data
  var channelData = buffer.getChannelData(0);
  for (var i = 0; i < sampleRate; i++) {
    channelData[i] = Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * frequency * i / (sampleRate));
  }

  // create audio source node.
  var source = audioContext.createBufferSource();
  source.buffer = buffer;
  source.connect(audioContext.destination);

  // finally start to play
  source.start(0);
}


//code
let A = document.getElementById('green');
let B = document.getElementById('red');
let C = document.getElementById('blue');
let D = document.getElementById('yellow');

function reset(color) {
  if (color == 'green') {
    A.style.backgroundColor = '#3f3';
    A.style.boxShadow = '0 0 0 0';
  } else if (color == 'red') {
    B.style.backgroundColor = "#f33";
    B.style.boxShadow = '0 0 0 0';
  } else if (color == 'blue') {
    C.style.backgroundColor = "#33f";
    C.style.boxShadow = "0 0 0 0";
  } else if (color == 'yellow') {
    D.style.backgroundColor = "#ff3";
    D.style.boxShadow = '0 0 0 0';
  }
}

let roundList = [];

const colors = ['green', 'red', 'blue', 'yellow'];

let expectedInput = ''

function randomColor() {
  // for(let i = 0; i <= roundList.length; i++){
  //     reset(roundList[i]);   
  // }
  let result = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 4);
  switch (result) {
    case 1:
      result = 'green';
      A.style.backgroundColor = '#8f8';
      A.style.boxShadow = '0 0 20px #8f8';
      playFrequency(440);
      setTimeout(function() {
        reset('green')
      }, 400);
      break;
    case 2:
      result = 'red';
      B.style.backgroundColor = '#f88';
      B.style.boxShadow = '0 0 20px #f88';
      playFrequency(554.3653);
      setTimeout(function() {
        reset('red')
      }, 400);
      break;
    case 3:
      result = 'blue';
      C.style.backgroundColor = '#88f';
      C.style.boxShadow = '0 0 20px #88f';
      playFrequency(659.2551);
      setTimeout(function() {
        reset('blue')
      }, 400);
      break;
    case 4:
      result = 'yellow';
      D.style.backgroundColor = '#ff8';
      D.style.boxShadow = '0 0 20px #ff8';
      playFrequency(880);
      setTimeout(function() {
        reset('yellow')
      }, 400);
      break;
    default:
      console.log('not 1');
      break;
  }
  expectedInput = result;
  roundList.push(expectedInput);
  // console.log(roundList);
}

let score = 0;
let scoreText = document.getElementById('score');
scoreText.innerText = `Score: ${score}`;
if (score == 1) {
  scoreText.innerText = "you win";
}


let actualInput;

function check(input) {
  switch (input) {
    case 'green':
      actualInput = 'green';
      break;
    case 'red':
      actualInput = 'red';
      break;
    case 'blue':
      actualInput = 'blue';
      break;
    case 'yellow':
      actualInput = 'yellow';
      break;
  }
  if (actualInput == expectedInput) {
    score += 1;
    scoreText.innerText = `Score: ${score}`;
    nextRound();
  } else {
    scoreText.innerText = "you lose"
  }
}

let timePassed = 0;

let buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('input-btn');

function stop() {
  clearInterval(repeat);
}

function nextRound() {

  // roundList.push(expectedInput);
  let delay = 500 * roundList.length;
  console.log(delay);
  let repeat = setInterval(randomColor, 500);
  setTimeout(repeat, delay);

  function stop() {
    clearInterval(repeat);
  }
  setTimeout(stop, delay);
}
```

```css
* {
  max-width: 1920px;
  max-height: 1080px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

#row1 {
  height: 400px;
}

.square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#green {
  background-color: #33ff33;
}

#red {
  background-color: #ff3333;
}

#blue {
  background-color: #3333ff;
}

#yellow {
  background-color: #ffff33;
}

.buttonbox {
  width: 100%;
}

.input-btn {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#greenbtn {
  background-color: inherit;
  border: none;
}

#redbtn {
  background-color: inherit;
  border: none;
}

#bluebtn {
  background-color: inherit;
  border: none;
}

#yellowbtn {
  background-color: inherit;
  border: none;
}

#start,
#score {
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="simon">
  <div class="row" id="row1"></div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-xxl-4"></div>
    <div class="col col-xxl-1">
      <div class="square mx-auto" id="green">
        <button class="input-btn" id="greenbtn" onclick="check('green')"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-xxl-1">
      <div class="square mx-auto" id="red">
        <button class="input-btn" id="redbtn" onclick="check('red')"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-xxl-1">
      <div class="square mx-auto" id="blue">
        <button class="input-btn" id="bluebtn" onclick="check('blue')"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-xxl-1">
      <div class="square mx-auto" id="yellow">
        <button class="input-btn" id="yellowbtn" onclick="check('yellow')"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-xxl-4"></div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-xxl-4"></div>
    <div class="col col-xxl-4">
      <button id="start" onclick="randomColor()" class="mx-auto">Start Game</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-xxl-4"></div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-xxl-4"></div>
    <div class="col col-xxl-4">
      <p id="score" class="mx-auto text-center"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-xxl-4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am willing to try anything, and if anything is unclear, lmk and I will be able to elaborate

Thank you!

Comment: I made a fiddle of your code but did not dig into why it does not seem to display properly. == AH for others this only displays proper at present in full screen mode.

Comment: FWIW you have a LOT of global variables here scattered throughout your code. I suggest you move them all to the top together - eventually you can use a class or an object to hold them all but this separates the variables from the functions.  Just IMHO.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Thank you for the suggestion. When I get everything working, I will reorganize my code. I'm kind of a beginner at this so I don't really know how javascript organization works lol

Comment: We all started at the beginning; no sweat there.  I did start an answer but the basic stuff did kind of get in the way of your actual problem for my brain, for example I did this `function check(input) {
  // replaced switch with:
  actualInput = input;
  if (actualInput == expectedInput) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setInterval()` function is set to call the `randomColor()` function every 500 milliseconds. `setTimeout()` function is only used to start the interval after a delay. Thus, `nextRound()` function is called multiple times in quick succession, the `randomColor()` function will be called multiple times before the previous `randomColor()` execution has completed.
So, clear the previous interval before starting a new one using the `clearInterval()` function. This will ensure that `randomColor()` is only called once every 500 milliseconds, regardless of how often the `nextRound()` function is called.
The amended code **could be** something like this

```
let repeat;   
function nextRound() {
  clearInterval(repeat);
  let delay = 500 * roundList.length;
  console.log(delay);
  repeat = setInterval(randomColor, 500);
  setTimeout(stop, delay);
}
```

Hope clears the hurdle and works for you. Do lemme know, if it works.